# How do I make the hover effect complete

Tags: html, css

[image]

I would like my hover effect to be complete, like in the picture. Mine highlights only a tiny bit around the text.
What am I missing? Please add an explanation to the solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/terzista/9vtpyojh/

css:

```
.nav
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 4;
    background-color:rgba(172,175,176,0.68);
}
.nav ul
{
    text-align: center;
}
.nav li
{
    width: 6em;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
}
.nav a{
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #D12C2C;
}

.nav li:hover
{
    color: #666;
    background-color: #ED8C8C;
}
.nav li:hover a
{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the following selectors in your css,

```
.nav ul
{
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
}
.nav li
{
    width: 6em;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
    padding:10px;
}
```

The only thing being highlighted is your li. If your ul has margin, then there will be space between the highlighted li and the rest of your ul (so to speak). Removing the margin from ul, then adding padding:10px to get that same "buffer zone" allows it to look the same, but also give the highlight you want.

```css
.nav
{
 margin:0 auto;
 width:100%;
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 z-index: 4;
 background-color:rgba(172,175,176,0.68);
}
.nav ul
{
 text-align: center;
    margin:0;
}
.nav li
{
 width: 6em;
 letter-spacing:0.1em;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase; 
    padding:10px;
}
.nav a{
 /*display: inline-block;*/
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #D12C2C;
}

.nav li:hover
{
 color: #666;
 background-color: #ED8C8C;
}
.nav li:hover a
{
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="nav">
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
   
  </ul>
 </nav>
</section>
```